# scryRenderedComponentsWithType returns an empty array

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

I have the following test for a React app:

```
it('has 7 NavBarItems', () => {
    const component = ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<App />);
    const navBarItems = ReactTestUtils.scryRenderedComponentsWithType(
        component,
        NavBarItem);

    expect(navBarItems.length).toEqual(7);
});
```

When the `App` component is rendered in a non-test environment, a NavBar with 7 NavBarItem child components is created at the top of the screen, to facilitate navigation throughout the app.

The `NavBarItem` class is as follows:

```
class NavBarItem extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div id={this.props.id}
                className={"NavBarItem" + (this.props.active ? " active" : "") + (this.props.visible ? "" : " hidden")}
                onClick={e => this.props.navBarClick(e.target.id)}>
                {this.props.title}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

However, the test always fails, because `scryRenderedComponentsWithType` always returns an empty array, even when I put add calls to `jest.dontMock` for both `App` and the file from which `NavBarItem` is imported. Am I using it wrong, or is what I want just not possible?

Comment: did you every figure this out?

Comment: Note: scryRenderedComponentsWithType does NOT work with new stateless components introduced in react v0.14.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have imported both `react` and `react-dom` to the test, as well as `App` and `NavBarItem` components. If we can't see the entire file it's harder to help.

...If that didn't help:
Have you tried other methods? Like:

```
scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithClass(component, NavBarItem);`
```